# Asynchronous requests from angular

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs

I have a method in service to get httprequest from another server and in the components console get null of value `ollayer` but data is not null

```
ollayer={};
```

service:

```
getLayer(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<olLayer>(
  'http://localhost:3000/geomap/getlayer',
);
}
```

components:

```
this.olservice.getLayer().subscribe((data) => {
  this.ollayer = data;
  console.log(data)
});

console.log(this.ollayer)
```

Comment: move your console log of ollayer inside subscribe because else your console log of ollayer will get precedence over assignment due to asynchronous calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behaviour is fine, that's how asynchronous pipelines work.

For whatever reason you need the data, for example, to update a view on your web page, you have to do it in the subscribe scope. For example, you are updating this.ollayer inside the subscribe, so any view properly binded to that variable will update when the request is done.

Edit: it is ok for data being null on your second log because data may not have arrived yet. But it is **not ok** to be null on the log inside the subscribe.